# WebView doesn't work PID: 31928 | Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView); //this is line 16
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
}
```

This is my simple code.
When I start Application I get this error: **PID: 31928**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.webviews/com.example.webviews.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.webkit.WebView

at com.example.webviews.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
```

I cannot find solution enywere.

Comment: The thing you called "webView" is not a WebView

Comment: Can you add your `activity_main` code?